# Passing data to signal callbacks without access to the Request/Response cycle

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a pre-packaged Scrapy spider and pipeline and want to use that in an already existing Twisted application, but I need to pass additional information (a single string) to the receiver of the [item_scraped](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#item-scraped) signal. For example purposes, I've written a script that summarizes what I've tried so far that uses the [dirbot](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot) example package:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python2
 from dirbot import settings as dbs
 from dirbot.spiders.dmoz import DmozSpider
 from functools import partial
 from scrapy import signals, log
 from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
 from scrapy.settings import Settings
 from twisted.internet import reactor


 # ---------------
 # This gets called
 # def item_scraped(item, response, spider):
 #     return item
 # ---------------


 # ------------
 # This does, but the signal dispatching system raises an exception:
 # exceptions.ValueError: unknown receiver type <functools.partial object at 0x7fa59c4d11b0> <type 'functools.partial'>
 def foo(something, item, response, spider):
     1/0

 # item_scraped = partial(foo, 1)
 # ------------


 def bla():
     something = 0  # noqa

     # -----------------
     # This doesn't
     def item_scraped(item, response, spider):
         1/something
     # -----------------

     log.start()
     settings = Settings()
     settings.setmodule(dbs)
     spider = DmozSpider()
     crawler = Crawler(settings)

     crawler.signals.connect(item_scraped,
                             signal=signals.item_scraped)
     crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
     crawler.configure()
     crawler.crawl(spider)
     return crawler.start()

 reactor.callWhenRunning(bla)
 reactor.run()
```

As you can see, the only way to get Scrapys signal system to call my callback is to make it a non-partial, module-level accessible function and I fail to see how I could pass additional data to that without putting that data into a global variable (this all uses Twisted under the hood and `bla` is itself a callback of something else, so the global variable approach would probably involve lots of locking very fast).

/edit since it seems it's a bit unclear what I'm trying to do:
The `item_scraped` callback is supposed to get some data from the received item and do something with that, in my case sending it to an IRC channel (so the variable `something` from my example would be the name of the IRC channel and the `item_scraped` callback needs access to that to send it to the correct channel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I completely understand what you are trying to do, but since `spider` is passed around everywhere, why don't you set your additional info as an attribute of that object? Like `spider.mystuff = 'some_data'`. It's actually a preferred method of passing spider related data around.

Comment: Hm, I guess that works, but feels pretty hacky. You mention this is a preferred method - is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I men't it's quite common to carry `spider` related data as object attributes, they even use if for spider arguments passed: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/fbb1078f58604f02c7fd84d35e3d46e6e4e1935f/scrapy/spider.py#L30